# Do Apple retail stores allow trade-ins?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-store

Is it possible to trade my 2009 MacBook Pro for store credit or something?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Apple has a [Reuse and Recycling Program](http://www.apple.com/recycling/computer/) where you can get a Gift Card for the value of your computer.  Of course, what value they might consider it to have is another question.

Comment: That Program does not seem to be available at the retail stores, though. It talks about mailing it to them.

Comment: I don't see the problem. You are still getting the store credit that you can use in the store...

Answer (score -2):

because to get the information from the old computer to the new after mailing in the computer would not be possible, and to buy the new one before mailing in the old would mean the "store credit" could not be used on that purchase.